# Cannot bind keyboard shortcut to .sh

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, script

elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki

I am trying to create a keybinding (like CTRL+Z) to a script file, but it never executes.

Steps:

```
System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom -> Add
```

I have tried:
1.) full path, /home/me/myscript.sh, 
2.) bash /home/me/myscript.sh
3.) copying the script to /usr/bin

Nothing seems to work. I have create other custom bindings to things like xkill and it works fine, just cannot get it to run a script file.

Any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that it was actually running the script but not showing the terminal.  I validated this by launching chrome from inside the bash script -- so that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add '-c' to the bash command.  This worked for me:

```
bash -c <full path to script>
```

E.g.,

```
bash -c /home/me/myscript.sh
```

Comment: Thank you but i found out the issue, it works fine with or w/o -c -- it was just not showing the terminal.